# CakePHP - can add users, but the users can't login()

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I can add users fine, and they show up in the database, but when I input their username and password into the login form, I get "Invalid username and password, try again." I've set it up so that it asks for login details when trying to edit or add a post to the page, as well as when clicking on the "Login" link.

The user model is User.php:

```
class User extends AppModel {
public $validate = array(
    'username' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank',
            'message' => 'A username is required'
        )
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'required' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank',
            'message' => 'A password is required'
        )
    ),
    'role' => array(
        'valid' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        )
    )
);

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this -> data[$this -> alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this -> data[$this -> alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher -> hash(
            $this -> data[$this -> alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

UsersController.php:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this -> Auth -> allow('add', 'logout');
}

public function login() {
    if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
        if ($this -> Auth -> login()) {
            return $this -> redirect($this -> Auth -> redirectUrl());
        }
        $this -> Flash -> error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}

public function logout() {
    return $this -> redirect($this -> Auth -> logout());
}

public function index() {
    $this -> User -> recursive = 0;
    $this -> set('users', $this -> paginate());
}

public function view($id = null) {
    $this -> User -> id = $id;
    if (!$this -> User -> exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    $this -> set('user', $this -> User -> findById($id));
}

public function add() {
    if ($this -> request -> is('post')) {
        $this -> User -> create();
        if ($this -> User -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
            $this -> Flash -> success(__('The user has been saved'));
            return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this -> Flash -> error(
            __('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
        );
    }
}

public function edit($id = null) {
    $this -> User -> id = $id;
    if (!$this -> User -> exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this -> request -> is('post') || $this -> request -> is('put')) {
        if ($this -> User -> save($this -> request -> data)) {
            $this -> Flash -> success(__('The user has been saved'));
            return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this -> Flash -> error(
            __('This user could not be saved. Please, try again.')
        );
    } else {
        $this -> request -> data = $this -> User - findById($id);
        unset($this -> request -> data['User']['password']);
    }
}

public function delete($id = null) {

    $this -> request -> allowMethod('post');

    $this -> User -> id = $id;
    if (!$this -> User -> exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    if ($this -> User -> delete()) {
        $this -> Flash -> success(__('User deleted'));
        return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this -> Flash -> error(__('User was not deleted.'));
    return $this -> redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

AppController.php:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    'Flash',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'posts',
            'action' => 'index'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
            )
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this -> Auth -> allow('index', 'view');
}
}
```

login.ctp:

```
<div class="users form">
    <?php echo $this -> Flash -> render('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this -> Form -> create('user'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <?php echo __('Please enter you username and password'); ?>
            </legend>
            <?php
                echo $this -> Form -> input('username');
                echo $this -> Form -> input ('password');
            ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this -> Form -> end(__('Login')); ?>
</div>
```

The password seems to hash fine. I've looked around at some similar questions, but none seem to solve my problem. Version is CakePHP 2.8.5.
I can't spot an error in my coding. Why does it always give me "Invalid username and password, try again."?

Comment: Is the password field in the database long enough to take the hashed password? If its not, it will just truncate the password and it will never validate correctly

Comment: Try checking the query that Cake uses to retrieve the user.

Comment: @mcgowan.b The password in the database was given VARCHAR(255), so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ drmonkeyninja Sorry I'm quite new to this, would that be the part in the controller or the model?

Answer (score -1):

Change this code and try its work for you

`'authorize' => array('Controller')` replace this with  `'authorize' => array('User')`
 and `if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin')` replace with `if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin' || $user['role'] === 'author')`

thanks

Comment: try edited answer ...replace || with && in if condition

Comment: No effect either I'm afraid.